# gdb viewing correct stack of a thread .

Tags: multithreading, gdb

I am new to gdb . 
I have an application which opens multiple threads . At a particular time I find that my application is misbehaving  . I need to debug my application . 
I run gdb and attach it to running application  , and switch to a thread using thread XYZ  . 
On doing bt i see that  all the thread goes into conditional wait and i am unable to debug the threads ie unable to get the true picture of the application thread stack.

I hence thought of creating a core file using gcore .

However when i open the gcore file in my gdb , i still see all threads in pthread conditional wait .

How to debug my application ?

Comment: "application is misbehaving" -- exactly how is it misbehaving? Is it not responding, or is it doing something incorrect?  If the former, GDB is showing you true state of threads (the app is deadlocked). If the latter, GDB appears to be causing your app to deadlock, which is an entirely different problem.

Answer (score 0):

This situation when all the threads stuck on a synchronization is called "[deadlock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock)". It often happens because of algorithmic error or/and synchronization failure (like [data-race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition)) which occurred before the program enters the deadlock state. Thus gdb shows your rather the results of the failure, but not the root case.

There are plenty of tools which are more convenient to debug multithreading errors than gdb, like [Intel Inspector XE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inspector-xe) or open-source alternatives like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

I personally tend to use more traditional means like debug assertions and logging in order to catch the point of the failure.

Comment: AFAICT, neither Intel Inspector nor Valgrind will help debugging a deadlock.

Comment: Intel Inspector cannot detect a Deadlock problem involving more than four threads. According to the [docs](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/inspector/lin/ug_docs/GUID-07E441C6-BBB2-47EC-8C62-81FC0F6FF78E.htm)

Comment: @EmployedRussian, as for Valgrind, I didn't use it, but I know it has some race detection capabilities.